# Material UI Autocomplete Custom ListboxComponent accessibility

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I created custom ListboxComponent for MUI Autocomplete component (MUI v4). How to satisfy accessibility features (navigating through options clicking Arrows)?

```
<Autocomplete
    ListboxComponent={(props) => <ul {...props}>
        {props?.children.map(element => 
           <li {...element.props}>{element.props.children}</li>
        )}
    </ul>}
/>
```

I tried to set tabIndex=0 or -1, but nothing changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create custom ListboxComponent like below and pass ref.

```
const ListboxComponent = React.forwardRef(function ListboxComponent(
  props,
  ref
) {
  const { children, ...other } = props;

  return (
    <ul {...other} ref={ref}>
      <li>{children}</li>
    </ul>
  );
});
```

complete code is here.
[enter link description here](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-5hn7hv?file=/demo.js)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you. Yeah I followed such approach last week and it's working. And forgot to add answer to my problem :)